# batch script assingn variable from command

Tags: windows, batch-file

when i execute following command to check the status of a network adapter for Local Area Connection:

```
netsh interface show interface "Local Area Connection" | find "Administrative state"
```

it will output the following:

```
Administrative state: Enabled
```

or

```
Administrative state: Disabled
```

how do i get the **enabled** or **disabled** to variable into batch script? I know in linux bash, it will be something like this:

```
MY_VAR1=$(some_command | grep "someString$" | xargs);
```

how to do it in windows batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think again

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface "Local Area Connection" ^| find "Administrative state"') do set var=%%i
```

will assign "Enabled" or "Disabled".

Using `"tokens=2 deims=:"` will assign

```
" Enabled             "
```

or

```
" Disabled            "
```

which can be proved by

```
echo +%var%+
```

(the `+` to show the spaces...)

Comment: what is your solution to remove the space?

Comment: `"tokens=3"` in place of `"tokens=2 delims=:"` (`3` got lost in transcription)

Comment: i used your "tokens=" i still get spacing

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface "Local Area Connection" ^| find "Administrative state"') do set var=%%i
```

use % instead of %% at command-line. `;)`